# Understanding client/server relation c++

Tags: server, client, chat

I want to build a simple client/server application that allows two different computers to send messages back and forth, i.e. some type of chat messenger. What I'm having trouble understanding is how once I've coded up my client/server application, where the server program will reside.

For example, if I have just two people connected to a server talking, the server program they should be talking to would reside somewhere, which they both talk to, and it relays their messages back to the client on each computer.

So once I have this server, where would I put it so both parties can talk? Do I actually have to host it somewhere, i.e. buy space on the internet, or could I skip that somehow, and allow two computers to simply talk over the internet without an intermediate.

Comment: As long as both clients know the address of the computer that's running the server, it can run anywhere. Even on the same machine as one of the clients. (And if you know each others' addresses, you can communicate directly without a server.)

Comment: If this is going to be limited to two people you could just host it on the same computer you use the client with (essentially becoming the host yourself).

Comment: @Floris Velleman So I could host the server on my own machine, and distribute the client program to the other person? That would work.

Comment: @molbdnilo, My only problem with that is what happens if I, or the other person, decide to use it on another computer. Then I have to have some way to resolve that computers IP address. Ideally, I want to be able to open up the program on any computer and resolve the IP address via, nicknames or something else assigned by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can just run the program on your own server. That will allow you to connect to that server from any location (if you set this up) and use the client with that server.

> Ideally, I want to be able to open up the program on any computer and resolve the IP address via, nicknames or something else assigned by the user.

This would be solved by putting up your own server. If you do not have a server you could go for a place that hosts your application (probably costs money).

You could also run it from the computer you start the client from but that would require the other user to connect to that computer rather then having a static location for your server (and you allowing that/firewall).